# how to put div/ image below div/image as in card game solitaire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am thinking to implement a demo,in which user can move a image or div below the image/div as we saw in card game solitaire .User can move card below the give card .If user pick the card put other position (where above card is not present it back to it original position).can you suggest me where I will start .I make div as image .I want to move bottom div to below the above div .can we achieve  In jQuery

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MbJJ6/397/)

```
<div id="red_card" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;float:left ; margin: 10px 10px"></div>
<div id="yellow_card" style="background:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;    margin: 10px 10px;
     "></div>
<div id="blue_card" style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;    margin: 10px 10px;
     "></div>
<div id="black_card" class="footer" style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;    margin: 10px 10px;
     "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="red card" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px;float:left ; margin: 10px 10px"></div>
 <div class="yellow card" style="background:yellow;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;    margin: 10px 10px;
"></div>
 <div class="blue card" style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;float:left;    margin: 10px 10px;
"></div>
<div class="black card" class="footer" style="background:black;width:100px;height:100px;   float:left; margin: 10px 10px;
"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.card{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.yellow{
    top:20px;
}

.blue{
    top:40px;
}

.black{
    top:60px;
}
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4Trg/

Comment: it is wrong , i need user can swip card or div different position

Comment: you understand wrong i need same layout using putting the card from one side to another

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted a static layout.

Answer (score 0):

In html overlapping divs have what is called a 'stack order'. The stack order determines which div/image/whatever is on top of the other. To help the browser decide what the stack order should be you can use z-index in your css.

```
z-index: 5
```

Elements with a higher z-index will always display on top of elements with a lower z-index. jQuery can change the z-index like this:

```
$('.firstCard').css('z-index', '15');
```

or whatever. Simply set up your cards to change position and change z-index based on clicks.